# KnockoutJS: ko.mapping.toJS, but do NOT ignore computed properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, frontend, knockout-mapping-plugin

In KnockoutJS, we can go

```
ko.mapping.toJS(object)
```

and get our object returned with observables and whatnot converted to vanilla Javascript object. Now, ko.mapping.toJS ignores computed properties. I have a scenario where I basically would like the functionality of ko.mapping.toJS to retain my pureComputed fields with whatever value they had at the time.

I've looked into the documentations page, but it looks like the "mapping options" are for the fromJS method, not toJS.

Any way I can convert my Knockout Object to a JS object but retain the pureComputeds being regular properties in the output?

Comment: Works for me in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/3b9xpjkt/1/

Comment: Hmm, I see. I am also able to get the computeds to show just fine in the output if I do a random test in a browser console. For some reason the project proper leaves computeds out. Perhaps there is some Knockout setting that is initialized at cross purposes with what I want. Will try to find such a setting now

Comment: Ah, I switched to using "ko.toJS" rather than "ko.mapping.toJS" just now. The output of ko.toJS does include the computed values just like I want.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from ko.mapping.toJS to ko.toJS and the output of ko.toJS does include the computed properties like I want, so that seems to be all I need.